# Flask Post Image Binding Error Parameter 2

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I keep getting this error when I run my Python FLASK web application when trying to create an Image Post for my PostForm

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO posts (title, content, post_image, date_posted, slug, poster_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Home Office Garden', '

Home Office Garden, getting the best of Life

\r\n', <FileStorage: 'hog1.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, '2022-05-26 20:53:19.609803', 'Home Office Garden', 1)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)

This is the Code I'm Working with, what do I do:

[The IMAGE CONTAINS THE CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovOr6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to this question I asked a few weeks ago:

```py
@app.route('/add-post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_post():
    form = PostForm()
            
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        poster = current_user.id
        post = Posts(title=form.title.data, content=form.content.data, file=form.file.data, poster_id=poster, slug=form.slug.data)

        if request.files['file']:
            upload.file = request.files['file']

            filename = secure_filename(upload.file.filename)

            file_name = str(uuid.uuid1()) + "_" + filename
            
            saver = request.files['file']

            post.file = file_name

            try:
                db.session.add(post)
                db.session.commit()
                saver.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name))
                flash("User Updated Successfully !")
                return render_template("add_post.html",
                    form=form)
            except:
                flash("Error! Looks Like There Was a Problem... Try Again!")
                return render_template("add_post.html",
                    form=form)
        else:
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("User Updated Successfully !")
            return render_template("add_post.html",
                form=form)
        
        form.title.data = ''
        form.content.data = ''
        form.slug.data = ''

        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template("add_post.html",
            form=form,
            id = id or 1)
```